# Небольшая проблема с библиотекой tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pylint

Работаю в VS Code. Использую `from tkinter import *`, однако редактор подчёркивает `from` жёлтым. В консоли показывается ровно 100(сто) проблем типа:

```
{
    "resource": "/C:/Python37-32/test-1.py",
    "owner": "python",
    "code": "unused-wildcard-import",
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Unused import enum from wildcard import",
    "source": "pylint",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 1
}
```

При этом работе, вроде бы, не мешает.

Comment: pylint - это утилита, которая находит *потенциальные* проблемы в коде (линтер, статический анализатор кода). Т.е. то на что pylint ругается - это не ошибки, но лучше так не делать. В частности, лучше не использовать импорт по звездочке.

Comment: Если быть более точным, то похоже, что ругается на то, что вы импортировали из модуля tkinter все, но не все используете. Решение - опять же, не использовать импорт по звездочке.

Comment: Да, но, если использую другие способы импорта, root = Tk() показывается, как ошибка. Tkinter только начал изучать и везде рекомендуется именно from tkinter import *

Comment: Я обычно использую вариант импорта `import tkinter as tk`, тогда перед всеми именами из этого модуля нужно добавить `tk.`: `root = tk.Tk()`. `...и везде рекомендуется именно from tkinter import *` - не рекомендуется, а традиционно используется. Но в целом для Python это не лучшая практика.

Comment: @insolor `from tkinter import*` это может не очень хорошо , но удобно :)

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, посреди проезжей части тоже может быть ходить хорошо и удобно - пока вас случайно не собьет машина. Best practices придуманы не для того чтобы было удобно, а чтобы не было потенциальных проблем в будущем.

Comment: А что не так с таким способом? Ну да чуть-чуть медленнее. Ну еще большой вопрос что лучше:
писать `tk` по сто раз , или один раз сделать не совсем правильно. ;)